# UTF-8 hex to unicode code point (only math)

Tags: math, unicode, utf-8, hex

Let's take this table with characters and HEX encodings in Unicode and UTF-8.
Does anyone know how it is possible to convert UTF-8 hex to Unicode code point using only math operations?
E.g. let's take the first row. Given `227`, `129` `130` how to get `12354`?
Is there any simple way to do it by using only math operations?

| Unicode code point | UTF-8 | Char |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30 42 (12354) | e3 (227) 81 (129) 82 (130) | あ |
| 30 44 (12356) | e3 (227) 81 (129) 84 (132) | い |
| 30 46 (12358) | e3 (227) 81 (129) 86 (134) | う |

* Source: https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=12288&unicodeinhtml=hex

Comment: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3629#section-3

Comment: Bitwise AND(&), OR(|) and left-shifting(<<): `((227 & 0x0f) << 12) | ((129 & 0x3f) << 6) | (130 & 0x3f)` -> `12354`.  Note this is fixed math for a 3-byte UTF-8 sequence without checking for invalid sequences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tbdym9ZtepQ&t=832s&ab_channel=Intermation) is the perfect source (**watch from 6:15**), but here is its summary and code sample in golang. With letters I mark bits taken from UTF-8 bytes, hopefully it makes sense. When you understand the logic it's easy to apply bitwise operators):

| Bytes | Char | UTF-8 bytes | Unicode code point | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-byte (ASCII) | E | 1. 0xxx xxxx 0**100 0101** or `0x45` | 1. 0xxx xxxx 0100 0101 or `U+0045` | no conversion needed, the same value in UTF-8 and unicode code point |
| 2-byte | Ê | 1. 110x xxxx 2. 10yy yyyy 110**0 0011** 10**00 1010** or `0xC38A` | 0xxx xxyy yyyy 0000 1100 1010 or `U+00CA` | 1. First 5 bits of the 1st byte 2. First 6 bits of the 2nd byte |
| 3-byte | あ | 1. 1110 xxxx 2. 10yy yyyy 3. 10zz zzzz 1110 **0011** 10**00 0001** 10**00 0010** or `0xE38182` | xxxx yyyy yyzz zzzz 0011 0000 0100 0010 or `U+3042` | 1. First 4 bits of the 1st byte 2. First 6 bits of the 2nd byte 3. First 6 bits of the 3rd byte |
| 4-byte |  | 1. 1111 0xxx 2. 10yy yyyy 3. 10zz zzzz 4. 10ww wwww 1111 0**000** 10**01 0000** 10**00 0100** 10**01 1111** or `0xF090_849F` | 000x xxyy yyyy zzzz zzww wwww 0000 0001 0000 0001 0001 1111 or `U+1011F` | 1. First 3 bits of the 1st byte 2. First 6 bits of the 2nd byte 3. First 6 bits of the 3rd byte 4. First 6 bits of the 4th byte |

##### 2-byte UTF-8

```golang
func get(byte1 byte, byte2 byte) {
    int1 := uint16(byte1 & 0b_0001_1111) << 6
    int2 := uint16(byte2 & 0b_0011_111)
    return rune(int1 + int2)
}
```

##### 3-byte UTF-8

```golang
func get(byte1 byte, byte2 byte, byte3 byte) {
    int1 := uint16(byte1 & 0b_0000_1111) << 12
    int2 := uint16(byte2 & 0b_0011_111) << 6
    int3 := uint16(byte3 & 0b_0011_111)
    return rune(int1 + int2 + int3)
}
```

##### 4-byte UTF-8

```golang
func get(byte1 byte, byte2 byte, byte3 byt3, byte4 byte) {
    int1 := uint(byte1 & 0b_0000_1111) << 18
    int2 := uint(byte2 & 0b_0011_111) << 12
    int3 := uint(byte3 & 0b_0011_111) << 6
    int4 := uint(byte4 & 0b_0011_111)
    return rune(int1 + int2 + int3 + int4)
}
```